# TightVNC On Another Network

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer, vnc-server

does anyone know how I can connect to my PC using TightVNC on another network? I have it working properly over a local network but I want to connect from different locations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official FAQ from TightVNC website :

How would I connect from the Internet to a machine in the internal network which is behind a router?
http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php#portfwd

> You should enable "port forwarding" in
>   your router's configuration. Port
>   forwarding allows passing external
>   connections to computers in the
>   internal network. Almost all routers
>   support this type of redirection.